# Portrait Images are cropped in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gridview, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to bind Landscape and Portrait Images to the grid control. The Landscape images are loaded correctly, but I'm facing problems when it comes to load portrait images. Their bottom part is cut off(overflowed) so the grid row can't load the image with it's full Height. I tried setting the Row property with `Height="Auto"` or `Height="*"` but that didn't work. Here is my XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsPrasanja}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock
                    Name="txtPrasanje"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Text="{Binding Tekst}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                <Image Name="imgPrasanje"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Source="{Binding Slika}"
                       Margin="0,5,0,0" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

How can I solve this without setting manually `Width` or `Height` to the Grid or the Image control?

**P.S.** The ItemsControl is part from another Grid control. It populates (Grid.Row="0") which I set to `Height="*"`

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I already tried all the `Stretch` properties, but it didn't have any effect. The image is still croped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will show you'r full code and xaml of this control? Is it is ListBox, try to add this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" to your control
```

Или просто покажи код всей контролы полностью